# o identificador 'DMBS_OUTPUT.CHARARR' deve ser declarado plsql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

Estou escrevendo o seguinte código plsql:

```
declare 
  tab      dmbs_output.chararr;
  qtlines  number             default 3;
  res      varchar2(100)      default null;
begin
  dbms_output.get_lines(tab, qtlines);
  dbms_output.put_line(
                       'Retornou: '||qtlines||' registros.');
  for i in 1..qtlines loop
    res := res||' '||tab(i);
  end loop;
  dbms_output.put_line('Pergunta: '||res);
  
end;
```

Ao executar utilizando o plsql developer ele me retorna o erro a seguir:

```
ERRO na linha 2:
ORA-06550: linha 2, coluna 12:
PLS-00201: o identificador 'DMBS_OUTPUT.CHARARR' deve ser declarado
ORA-06550: linha 2, coluna 12:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
ORA-06550: linha 6, coluna 25:
PLS-00320: a declaração do tipo desta expressão está incompleta ou incorreta
ORA-06550: linha 6, coluna 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: linha 10, coluna 22:
PLS-00320: a declaração do tipo desta expressão está incompleta ou incorreta
ORA-06550: linha 10, coluna 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Estou seguindo o exemplo do livro e está tudo de acordo! Agradeço quem puder me ajudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"Estou seguindo o exemplo do livro e está tudo de acordo"* se estiver mesmo assim tem um erro nesse livro e deveria reportar isso.

Não existe `dmbs_output` o correto é `dbms_output`, há um *typo* ai, veja a documentação aqui: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TTPLP/d_output.htm

Mude isso e vai funcionar, que aliás, está correto no resto do teu código. Em tempo, não esqueça de validar se o output está ligado ou nada vai aparecer no output, para ligar use `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON`